# Not breaking the egg

Tags: lateral-thinking

What is the simplest approach to make an raw egg fall for 2 meter and not breaking it?
*You can't catch it.

Hint 1:

> The answer do not require any physics principle nor any calculation

Hint 2:

> You don't need any extra item to achieve this objectives

Hint 3:

> "Raw egg", so you can't cook it

Hint 4:

> 2 meter is important

Comment: Would we catch it after it has fallen to 2 meters before reaching the ground?

Comment: Think other way, you almost got it.

Comment: Did it fall on a cot or so?

Comment: Please read hint 2 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably:

> Drop the egg 10 meters.  After .64 seconds, the egg falls 2 meters, but doesn't break.  Yet.

Alternative(s):

> Drop the egg .1 meters 20 times.  Cumulative falling distance is 2 meters.

Comment: An egg will break in your alternative scenario.

Comment: An alternative, Rot 13: `Gnxr vg hc vagb fcnpr, Vagreangvbany Fcnpr Fgngvba jvyy qb gura yrg tb bs gur rtt (qebc vg) naq vg jvyy snyy jvgubhg oernxvat. uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Vagreangvbany_Fcnpr_Fgngvba: Tenivgl ng gur nygvghqr bs gur VFF vf nccebkvzngryl 90% nf fgebat nf ng Rnegu'f fhesnpr, ohg bowrpgf va beovg ner va n pbagvahbhf fgngr bs serrsnyy`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to

> choose a suitable egg. An insect egg would work, or a turtle egg, or a dinosaur egg ...