# Dropping an egg on the floor

Tags: wordplay

How do you drop a raw egg on a concrete floor without breaking it?

Assume the egg is a standard chicken egg, dropped from the height of 2m.

Comment: This is a well-known riddle, @danielmathias's answer is correct.

Comment: Given [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89667/56238) I recommend that the tag is changed to [tag:wordplay] or else this isn't a puzzle

Comment: we used to have engineering challenges every year on how to drop a raw egg a couple of stories onto a hard surface without breaking the egg... turns out there are a lot of ways to do it

Comment: [XKCD 169](https://xkcd.com/169/) seems to be relevant here.

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate... Am I hallucinating?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 apparently you aren't hallucinating (yet). [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83551/not-breaking-the-egg) is the same question. The "2m" is suspiciously the same

Comment: @Adam Does not seem like the same question, but I concede it's similarly silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply:

> Just drop the egg. The concrete floor is not likely to break.

Answer (score 2):

one way is

> drop it from a very low height (1 mm or so)

Comment: Added some more precision to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer:

> Drop it on a planet with a *very* low gravity. The speed it will get from a 2m drop will not be sufficient to break it.